# How to create if statement on arguments of the resource?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

I have for loop that creates 2 ec2s on aws. I want to pass user_data argument on the only one of them, so my idea is to create if statement to accomplish this.
Something like this:

Instance EC2

```
resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  count                       = length(var.vms)
  ami                         = data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id
  instance_type               = var.instance_type
  key_name                    = var.key_name
  get_password_data           = false
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  vpc_security_group_ids      = [var.secgr_id]
  iam_instance_profile        = aws_iam_instance_profile.ec2_instance_profile.name
  user_data = var.vms[count.index] == "some-vm-name" ? "${file(var.file_name)}" : null
  tags = {
    Name = var.vms[count.index]
  }
  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true
  }
}
```

It actually choses VM that i want, but the script is never executed that i pass through file function?

Is this possible to do?

Comment: When Terraform shows you the plan to create all of the instances of this resource, you should see it say either `user_data = null` or `user_data = "(file contents)"` depending on the result of this condition. If you can see Terraform showing that `user_data` is set for the particular instance you intended this to be set for then that would suggest a problem with the software in your AMI, rather than a problem with the Terraform configuration. If you are using cloud-init in your AMI then you may find more information in the cloud-init logs.

Comment: I added here more clear question, maybe you can take a look and i will delete this question. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72526661/if-statement-in-terraform-on-user-data-argument-of-the-resource-ec2-instance-doe?noredirect=1#comment128121683_72526661